# Create a Integrated Editor For Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

How can I create an integrated file editor in Visual Studio like as Crystal Reports Editor or RDLC Report Editor

more information:
as you might be work with crystal report, when you click on your crystal report file "rpt file" in your solution bar , it'll open in an integrated report editor called "crystal report editor" inside vs.net like as source files. I want to design my own editor that integrated in vs.net

visual studio.net 2008

Comment: Can you specify more your question please?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio ? (There are much better support for doing this kind of thing easily in the upcoming Visual Studio 2010, but it is possible in previous versions too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS is easily extended.

The basic extension method is to write macros, but if you wish to implement an embedded editor then you will need to get more advanced - an Add-in, Package, or for VS2010 you can now make an Extension.

Extensions are much better/easier to develop than addins, but fundamentally they both allow much the same thing - low level access to the internals of VS.

You can find a lot of information about addins and extensibility by searching on those terms, but here are a couple of useful starting points:

[mz tools](http://www.mztools.com/resources_vsnet_addins.aspx)
[MS extensibility center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx)
[MS forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/vsx/threads/)